# How can a create an SQL statement that offers multiple sum() totals?

Tags: sqlite

I have this table in SQLite3.

```
Name | Qty | Price | Category
-----------------------------
Z    | 1   | $25   | A
Y    | 2   | $50   | B
X    | 3   | $100  | A
W    | 1   | $6    | C
V    | 2   | $15   | B
U    | 1   | $26   | A
```

How can I get the total (qty * price) for each category and the total (qty * price) of all categories with a single SQL statement?  This is the output I am looking for:

```
A     - $351
B     - $130
C     - $6
Total - $487
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select category, sum(qty * price)
from your_table
group by category

union all

select 'Total' as category, sum(qty * price)
from your_table
```